# Setting a Cookie and Defining the Domain: Employee Site (set cookie) > Company Site

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, cross-domain, setcookie, web-traffic

I'm trying to filter out employee traffic in Google Analytics via cookie. Our company sets every employee's browser home page to our Intranet (Internal.com). Setting a cookie on Internal.com will give me the best chance at setting cookies for the majority of employees and setting them often.

The problem is, setting a cookie on Internal.com does not translate to Company.com in Google Analytics where I'm actually trying to filter out the traffic.

I do NOT have the ability to change the browser home page to a redirect, such as Company.com/internal > Internal.com.

Is there anyway to allow Company.com to see Internal.com cookies? Is there a way to inject the Google Analytics account ID into the SetCookie function so that it allows it to be read? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Have looked at this but not sure I understand fully: https://joshuatz.com/posts/2019/excluding-employee-traffic-from-google-analytics-pixels-and-more/#how-to-implement-cookie-based-exclusions

Comment: domainA.com cannot read domainB.com cookies. This violates [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @CrayonViolent even if i own both domains?

Comment: Or what if I implement the GA or GTM global site tag on Internal.com? I obviously wouldn't want to count those users/pageviews but they'd get filtered out anyway because they would be cookied.

Comment: Even if you own both domains, you cannot make javascript read a cookie from another domain. There are various methods for passing info from one domain to another but all involve doing some coding on both domains (even server-side coding for some of the solutions).